# SQL - Extract a numeric part of a variable length string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, extract, patindex

Here is an example:

[U_TipTon]=118.7->59.35;[U_Haulge]=428.28->214.14

I need to extract just 118.7->59.35 as Tipton, and 428.28->214.14 in another column as U_Haulage.

The length of the string is variable as well as the posision os my pattern word.

I am trying with Patindex but I cannot find the way.

Comment: Are you using mysql or other?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL there's SUBSTRING_INDEX, which extracts a substring based on a delimiter:

```
select
  substring_index(substring_index(x, '[U_TipTon]=', -1), ';', 1) as TipTon
  ,substring_index(substring_index(x, '[U_Haulge]=', -1), ';', 1) as Haulge
from
 (
   select '[U_TipTon]=118.7->59.35;[U_Haulge]=428.28->214.14' as x
 ) as dt
```

Edit:
In MS SQL Server it's more complicated:

```
select 
   substring(xHaulge, 1, charindex(';', xHaulge + ';')-1) as Haulge,
   substring(xTipTon, 1, charindex(';', xTipTon + ';')-1) as TipTon
from
 (
   select
      case when charindex('[U_Haulge]=', x) > 0 
           then substring(x, charindex('[U_Haulge]=', x) + len('[U_Haulge]='), 8000)
           else '' 
      end as xHaulge,
      case when charindex('[U_TipTon]=', x) > 0 
           then substring(x, charindex('[U_TipTon]=', x) + len('[U_TipTon]='), 8000) 
           else '' 
      end as xTipTon
   from 
    (
      select '[U_TipTon]=118.7->59.35;[U_Haulge]=428.28->214.14' as x
    ) as dt
 ) as dt
```

Comment: The idea would work for 1 specif row, but I have 4000 row, in which the position of this words, the numbers and length are different in each row.

Comment: Did you actually try my query on your data? It works exactly as requested as long as the name/value pairs are separated by semicolons..

Comment: As I am using SQL server and no mySQL don't know what function use to substitute substring_index

Comment: Why do you tag the query with mysql? And SQL is **not** MS SQL Server, it's generic Standard SQL. What's your SQL Server release?

Comment: Added a solution for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

case
         when charindex('Haulge',t.xField) > 0 then

substring( t.xField , charindex('Haulge',t.xField) + 8,case when charindex(';',substring( t.xField , charindex('Haulge',t.xField) + 8,LEN(t.xField))) = 0 
                                                        then LEN(t.xField) 
                                                        else  charindex(';',substring( t.xField , charindex('Haulge',t.xField) + 8,LEN(t.xField)))-1 end ) 
                                                        else '-' end [Haul Price]
,case
        when charindex('Tipton',t.xField) > 0 then

substring( t.xField , charindex('TipTon',t.xField) + 8,case when charindex(';',substring( t.xField , charindex('Tipton',t.xField) + 8,LEN(t.xField))) = 0 
                                                        then LEN(t.xField) 
                                                        else  charindex(';',substring( t.xField , charindex('Tipton',t.xField) + 8,LEN(t.xField)))-1 end ) 
                                                        else '-' end [Tip Price]
,case
        when charindex('AItmPr',t.xField) > 0 then

substring( t.xField , charindex('AItmPr',t.xField) + 8,case when charindex(';',substring( t.xField , charindex('AItmPr',t.xField) + 8,LEN(t.xField))) = 0 
                                                        then LEN(t.xField) 
                                                        else  charindex(';',substring( t.xField , charindex('AItmPr',t.xField) + 8,LEN(t.xField)))-1 end ) 
                                                        else '-' end [Additional Price]